# Finding Fonts that Look "Handwritten"

Tags: fonts

Is this possible to replicate this kind of font?

It's the blue one.
I like it because it's perfect to write examples of something where you don't want to use the same font.

[image: Font]

I'm getting this when using `XeLaTeX`

[image]

Comment: Does this help? http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Not actually. I didn't find any font that suits my needs. Do you know any?

Comment: some handwriting fonts are shown here: [Using handwriting font in proofs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/195798/579)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thank you, but there's nothing similar.

Comment: I edited the title from **replicating a font** to **Finding Fonts that Look "Handwritten"**.

Comment: How do you know you are using `xelatex`? That error can usually be taken as an accurate statement that you are *not* using either of the required engines.

Comment: Why don't you find some font you like using google and then use xelatex to use it?

Comment: @Joseph I wish I knew how to do that. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: @Ustanak use another editor, choose xelatex to compile, or just run xelatex "file-name".tex from the terminal in the same folder. See percuse's answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If you follow the link that I provided in my comment then you get to this overview site:

[image]

There is a big link saying **[Calligraphical and Handwritten Fonts](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/calligraphicalfonts.html)** which leads to this:

[image]

What else do you expect? In addition the comment of [barbara-beeton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579/barbara-beeton) also provides handwritten fonts.

Answer (score 2):

With Lua- and XeTeX engines you can use any (well almost) font you want. I searched for free handwritten fonts and stumbled upon *Architect's Daughter*

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily{\archw}{ArchitectsDaughter}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\texthw}{\archw}

\begin{document}

\texthw{jumped on} some stuff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Please read further [Proper way to change a font temporarily with fontspec](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/51717/proper-way-to-change-a-font-temporarily-with-fontspec) which I stole egreg's answer above from.

Comment: Very good answer! I would also comment that **Lua**tex maybe harder in the beginning. It took me long hours until I was able to finally use a system font (I got help from this community luckily).

Comment: I used your preamble but it doesn't compile. It says I need to use `XeLaTeX` (but I already chose this).

Comment: @Ustanak What's the error?

Comment: @percusse See my edited post.